# Removing first square brackets in every line with the content in it (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file `try.txt` that looks like this:

```
(SOME_PRINT): [a] content
(SOME_PRINT): [a] [b] content
```

If I have this pattern in the beginning of a line in the file: `(SOME_PRINT): [<word>]` (where `<word>` is a combination of letters and numbers only), so I would like to replace it with `(OTHER_PRINT):`.
For the file above, I would like to find a command that its execution will make the file become:

```
(OTHER_PRINT): content
(OTHER_PRINT): [b] content
```

I tried to run `sed -r -i 's/^\(SOME_PRINT\)\: \[.*\] /\(OTHER_PRINT\)\: /' try.txt`  , and got this output:

```
(OTHER_PRINT): content
(OTHER_PRINT): content
```

Can you explain why has `[b]` disappeared?

Comment: note that sed doesn't support non-greedy, but as specified in answers of the duplicate question, you can use the workaround in this case.. also, you can avoid having to escape the `()` by removing the `-r` option

Answer (score 1):

Just change your regex like this:

`sed -r -i 's/^\(SOME_PRINT\)\: \[[a-zA-Z0-9]\] /\(OTHER_PRINT\)\: /' try.txt`

Your error is that you this part of your regex is not precise enough: `\[.*\]`

`[a] [b]` can be catch by `\[.*\]`

On solution is to specify only characters that can be found between your square brackets. As you told about only alphanumeric characters, this can be done by this selector: `[a-ZA-Z0-9]`.

Another solution is to exclude the closing square bracket from the characters.

I often try my regex with https://regex101.com/. It's very cool and comprehensible.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link.